# Conformal maps question

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $\psi:\Bbb R^2\to \Bbb R^2$ be given by $\psi(x,y)=(u(x,y),v(x,y))$ where $u$ and $v$ are differentiable and satisfy $u_x=v_y, u_y=-v_x$. Prove that $\psi$ is a local conformal map from $\Bbb R^2-Q$ into $\Bbb R^2$ where $Q=\{(x,u)\in\Bbb R^2\mid u_x^2+u_y^2=0\}$. I might be missing something about conformal maps but I'm not sure where to go with this one.

Comment: What's your definition of local conformal map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The derivative (jacobian) $D\psi$ of $\psi$, which describes the best linear approximation of $\psi$ at any point, satisfies

$$D \psi = \left(\begin{array}{c,c} u_x & u_y \\ v_x & v_y \end{array}\right)
=
\left(\begin{array}{c,c} u_x & u_y \\ -u_y & u_x \end{array}\right)
$$

this is a rescaled rotation matrix -- both rescalings and rotations preserve angles. That is a good suggestion the map $\psi$ locally preserves angles, and therefore is conformal.

---

More precisely, take two curves $\gamma_1(t)$, $\gamma_2(s):\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R^2$ that intersect at some point $t_0$.  Their angle of intersection $\theta$ obeys:

$$cos(\theta) = \frac{\|\gamma_1'(t_0) \cdot \gamma_2'(t_0)\|}{\|\gamma_1'(t_0) \| \| \gamma_2'(t_0)\|}$$

We want to show $\psi$ preserves the angle between $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ at $t_0$.

Write the angle $\theta'$ the image curves $\psi \circ \gamma_1'$ and $\psi \circ \gamma_2'$ make when they intersect using the chain rule $(\psi\circ\gamma)' = (D\psi) \gamma'$

$$cos(\theta') = \frac{\|D\psi \gamma_1'(t_0) \cdot D\psi\gamma_2'(t_0)\|}{\|D\psi\gamma_1'(t_0) \| \| D\psi\gamma_2'(t_0)\|}$$

because we know $D\psi$ is just some scalar $s$ times a rotation $R$, we can manipulate the inner product (adjoint of rotation is opposite rotation):

$$cos(\theta') = \frac{\|sR \gamma_1'(t_0) \cdot sR\gamma_2'(t_0)\|}{\|sR\gamma_1'(t_0) \| \| sR\gamma_2'(t_0)\|}
= \frac{s^2\|R^{-1} R \gamma_1'(t_0) \cdot \gamma_2'(t_0)\|}
{s^2\|\gamma_1'(t_0) \| \| \gamma_2'(t_0)\|}$$
$$= \frac{\|D\psi \gamma_1'(t_0) \cdot D\psi\gamma_2'(t_0)\|}{\|D\psi\gamma_1'(t_0) \| \| D\psi\gamma_2'(t_0)\|} = cos(\theta) $$

Comment: Moreover, you will have to argue that $Q$ is the only subset of $\mathbb R ^2 $ where this breaks down.  I'm not sure what your preparation is so ask if you don't understand any of my steps.